# Resizing Console window C++

Tags: c++, console

AoA
   I have made a solitaire game in console window by using system("mode CON: COLS=140");
I dont know what happened but when I run the program now, it prints an error showing "mode not recognized" and the console width is set to 78 size (default), whereas the program(solitaire) runs fine on other machines.

```
RECT r;
HWND console = GetConsoleWindow();
GetWindowRect(console, &r); //stores the console's current dimensions
MoveWindow(console, r.left, r.top, 800, 600, TRUE);
```

this function runs upto 800x600 pixels(which is default), increasing the pixels shows no effect..
Is there any other way to increase the width of console width ?

Comment: Use SetConsoleWindowInfo() instead.  You also need to ensure that the buffer is big enough, use SetConsoleScreenBufferSize() first.

Comment: +1 for answer :) worked for me

Comment: You should not practice GUI in console. Knowledge that you gain is nearly useless. Practice GUI in windows projects and gain useful knowledge.

Comment: it was just a semester lab project in which there is a restriction to use console c++, thats why I used the API function :)

Comment: You could check a console-GUI library like ncurses

Comment: yeah i have used ncurses before... :)
next time, i will :)